# WebApi + Jquery + WebForms Login Lost the session

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I try to build a Login Method with c# + jquery + webapi but when the login are success, and redirect to home page, we lost the session data :(

what I need to do?

but when I access to the api I can see the session data, but when is redirected the data is lost :(

this is my login js file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dologin').click(function () {
        var postData = JSON.stringify({
            "username": $("#email").val(),
            "password": $("#password").val()
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "~/api/user/DoLogin",
            data: postData,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: callbackfunction,
            error: showerror
        });
    });
});
function showerror(result) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
function callbackfunction(result) {
    if (result) {
        window.location.replace("~/dashboard.aspx");
    } else {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
}
```

this is my api code:

```
[ActionName("Login")]
[Route("api/User/DoLogin/")]
[HttpPost]
public bool Login([FromBody]Models.User.User data)
{
     if (data.login())
     {
          return true;
     }
     else {
          return false;
     }
}
```

but the error thrown where is load Dashboard.aspx:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Models.Modelo.SessionHandler.LogguedUser.rol < 0 && Models.Modelo.SessionHandler.LogguedUser.status < 0)
            {
                Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you show the api code ?
can you show what call you make to see the login data in your api ?

Comment: here ya go :) if you can check pls

Comment: data is lost when redirecting, you should search internet for how to preserve data when redirecting

Comment: thanks this help me